# What could cause transient binocular vision loss?

Tags: eye, brain, mental-health, neurology, diagnostics

I have episodes of transient binocular vision loss. The progression of an episode is very predictable: I start noticing some letters missing in text. Slowly, it evolves to a point half of my vision is gone (for example, can't see my own right hand in front of me). It then improves until I can see perfectly again. All that lasts from 1 to 2 hours.

Those episodes happen once each 2 to 3 months. Sometimes I have almost a yer without one, sometimes I have 2 in a week. The episodes happen unpredictably and I couldn't associate a single variable to their occurrence. Sometimes I'm nervous, sometimes I'm happy. Sometimes I'm hungry, sometimes I'm not. Once I woke up with it. Nothing to correlate so far. This started when I was 15 years old, after I did a very wild, unhealthy diet based on "diet shakes". I almost starved and lost 20kg from obese to normal. It is probably related, but maybe not. I am 23 now. I probably had around 40 episodes so far.

I visited dozens of doctors already. Eyes checked, fine. I have done 3 brain MRIs, including one a few minutes after an episode, at the hospital. Fine. Nobody knows what I have, so I'm wandering around the internet - maybe here someone has an insight?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please read the duplicate question/answer. If it is not what you experience (the headache is not necessary), then please edit your question to indicate how it's different and flag for reopening. Thanks! :)